# How do I generate an array of Streams with type as enums in java with a default value

Tags: arrays, lambda, java-8, enums, java-stream

I have an enum as below

```
enum color
{
  red, blue, green;
}
```

I have to generate an array of colors with default color as blue

in old java(<8), I do this.

```
color[] myArray = new color[mySize];

for(int iter=0; iter<myArray.length; iter++)
  myArray[iter] = color.blue;
```

How do I use java Array Generator Stream code to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iterative version sounds good and I'll advise you to keep it. However, since you are curious on equivalent streams version, here it is.

```
color[] myArray = IntStream.range(0, size)
    .mapToObj(unused -> color.blue)
    .toArray(color[]::new);
```

You have to use an `IntStream`, creating a default `color.blue` in each iteration. Finally, use the `toArray` to create an array of enums.

Comment: well i asked stream version to have parallel processing. thanks.

Comment: https://ideone.com/xq43ep
the classical is better performing than the Stream version.

Comment: @Panther_Black the idiomatic approach still is `color[] myArray = new color[mySize]; Arrays.fill(myArray, color.blue);`, which is also the one with the biggest chance of highest performance.

Comment: Or else by initializing the array length only once like so: `for(int i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++)`